# app lock to lock apps in iphone

Tags: ios, passwords, lockscreen

I'm a newbie,and i'd like to create an app which allows to lock the apps such as Whatsapp and facebook which are being installed by the user using password, I will be very thankful if any one suggest any idea or any sample code to achieve this. Thanks in advance Waiting for reply.

Comment: it's impossible. forget about it

Comment: i'm not going to release this app in the app store just to try it with my phone for adhoc deployment –

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In iOS, apps operate as a non-privileged user. They can't change the global functioning of the system like you describe.

Apple does not want, and does not allow, third party apps to change the way a user's device functions.

What you want to do is not possible unless you jailbreak your device.

Comment: i'm not going to release this app in the app store just to try it with my phone for adhoc deployment

Comment: It's still not possible at the OS level. You can think of allowing other apps to run/not run is a Kernel function. 3rd party apps have no ability. to run as Kernel. (This isn't exactly how it works. It's an analogy.)